# browser.menus.onClicked.addListener not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Currently I'm working on my own Firefox extension and I've met the problem with adding listener to an `onclick` event for a context menu item.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My extension name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My extension description",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["menus"], 
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["index.js"]
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
browser.menus.create({
  id: 'my-ext-item',
  title: 'Custom ctx item',
  contexts: ['selection']
});

browser.menus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

`browser.menus.create()` apparently works fine, because the new item appear in my context menu. The problem is with catching a click event - it is never fires.

I've wrote above code according to the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/onClicked). I test it on `Firefox 97.0.1 x64`.

What did I wrong and what should I repair?

PS. I was trying with older `browser.contextMenus.create` and `browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution - `browser.menus.onClicked.addListener()` working properly, just there is a necessity to enable logging in browser settings.

First, go to `about:config` and find key `extensions.logging.enabled` and switch it to `true`. Then, display *Browser Console* from `Menu Bar -> Tools -> Browser Tools -> Browser Console` or by shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+J`.

> Be aware that *Browser Console* is not the same as *Firefox Developer
> Tools* (from F12 or Ctrl+Shitft+I)!

Last, but not least enable `Show Content Messages` in *Browser Console*

[image]